# Fetch in JavaScript for FastApi in localhost

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi

How can you use my Api made with FastAPI, from my localhost, from an external html, for example, it is my simple implementation of test:

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Item Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //var url = 'http://localhost:8000';
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {console.log(data)})
    </script>
    <h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but the return navigator(Safari) is:

> [Error] Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> [Error] Fetch API cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/ due to access
> control checks. [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not
> allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (127.0.0.1, line 0) [Error]
> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Origin null is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  (anonymous function)    promiseReactionJob

Comment: You need to enable CORS server-side: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: `Origin null is not allowed` - how are you loading the index.html? `http://`? `file:///`?

Comment: loaded in http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable CORS in your API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8000"
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

See more information about CORS [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/).

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.